# Firewall is blocking echo request on port 7 (TCP)

Tags: windows-7, firewall, tcp, echo

I have an app which needs to receive a message back from the server. With the firewall on, I do not get the message back. If I turn off the firewall I get the request back.

I have added some rules and I have opened port 7 in the firewall but the problem is still there.

Comment: If I turn off the firewall I get the request back. If I turn it on I don't receive the request back

Comment: I updated your question to make it clearer, [rollback](http://superuser.com/posts/625832/revisions) if you don't like it.

Comment: The fault is probably with the server (not sending the message out) but you've not provided any detail! What server is this?

Comment: What kind of server/firewall is this?

Comment: The server is my own laptop and the firewall is Windows 7 default firewall. The thing is that the devices can reach the server if the firewall is disabled, but I turn it on, the devices cannot reach it.

Comment: So, your laptop is acting like a server with Windows 7. And you're attempting to connect to it from another W7 machine? In that case, make sure you open your port for domain, public and private profiles.

Comment: I am attempting to connect to it from a mobile device but the thing is that I opened the port 7 for both profiles.